# Bootstrap Multiselect plugin filter uppercase

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select

I'm working on Bootstrap Multiselect, and I'm using bootstrap 3.1, and downloaded [this script](http://davidstutz.de/bootstrap-multiselect/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example28').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            enableFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: 150
        });
    });
</script>

<select id="example28" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="cheese">Ahmet Burak</option>
  <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
  <option value="mozarella">Mozzarella</option>
  <option value="mushrooms">Mushrooms</option>
  <option value="pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
  <option value="onions">Onions</option>
</select>
```

I tried many times to use filter. If I don't use first char uppercase in form, it doesn't find anything. How can I solve it?

Comment: can you be more clear about what first character are you talking about. Are you talking about the options display text? And if yes, do you want them the first character to be small?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I understand that you are talking about lowercase not working when you try to filter the results in your dropdown. Just **enable case insensitive filtering** & it should work -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example28').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        maxHeight: 150
    });
});
```

**Working Example of your code** - http://codepen.io/nitishdhar/pen/lHyas